# django NoReverseMatch at / TypeError - missing required positional arguments

Tags: python, django

```
path('administration/delete-post/', administration_views.delete_upload, name='delete_upload'),
path('administration/delete-post/<slug:post_slug>', administration_views.delete_upload, name='delete_upload'),
```

For some reason, when I added delete class, I had to add two url patterns.
When I comment out the first path, It gives me an error of

`Reverse for 'NoReverseMatch at /administration/`

`delete_upload' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['administration/delete\\-post/(?P<post_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']`

I even stated the slugs on html.

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <a href="{% url 'delete_upload' %}{{ post.slug }}">Delete Upload</a>
{% endif %}
```

With two same url patterns, it worked fine somehow, but now I want to add a confirmation page, and it's causing an error again.

views.py

```
def delete_upload(request, post_slug):
   post = get_object_or_404(VideoPost, slug=post_slug)
   if request.method == "POST":
       post.delete()
   context = {
       "post": post
   }
   return render(request, "administration/confirm_delete.html", context)
```

confirm_delete.html

```
{% block content %}
<form action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Are you sure you want to delete</h1>
    <p>{{post.title}}</p>
    <a href="../">Cancel</a><input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

error

```
TypeError at /administration/delete-post/
delete_upload() missing 1 required positional argument: 'post_slug'
```

It directs me to confirm_delete page correctly with the slugs on url, but when I click confirm, the slug is gone on the url and it's causing the error it seems.

I see the problem, but I can't fix it... please help.
Thank you for any helps

Comment: You are expecting post_slug argument in your method, give default paramter there and try with that for example

def delete_upload(request, post_slug="blabla"):

and add control as well for default parameter

Comment: Why do you have two URL patterns that refer to the same view?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I really don't know. It just works this way for some reason.

Comment: remove this, `path('administration/delete-post/', administration_views.delete_upload, name='delete_upload'),` and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `path('administration/delete-post/',`  in your `urls.py` file

In your HTML `template` pass your `post.slug` along with the url namespace

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <a href="{% url 'delete_upload' post.slug %}">Delete Upload</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using *url* template tag incorrectly. In html you need replace

```
<a href="{% url 'delete_upload' %}{{ post.slug }}">Delete Upload</a>
```

with

```
<a href="{% url 'delete_upload' slug=post.slug %}">Delete Upload</a>
```